# Moving to one storyboard to another via a class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

i have  2 storyboard currently controller reach in first viewcontroller. i want to move to second storyboard via  a class

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"CMS_OrganisationManagement" bundle:nil];
                                   UIViewController *viewcontroller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WS_OrganisationSelectViewController"];
                                   UIWindow *window;
                                   window.rootViewController = viewcontroller;
```

it doesn't work
and i try this method also.it also not work

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"CMS_OrganisationManagement" bundle:nil];
                                   UIViewController *viewcontroller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WS_OrganisationSelectViewController"];
                                   UINavigationController * navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];
                                   [navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Present it with your current navigationController:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController animated: NO];
```

Or present it from current VC:

```
[self presentViewController: viewController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: class have no relation with the viewcontroller.so there is no navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

You have to add navigationController as rootViewController

```
 UIStoryboard * storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"CMS_OrganisationManagement" bundle:nil];
 UIViewController *viewcontroller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WS_OrganisationSelectViewController"];
 UINavigationController *NC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];
 UIWindow *window;
 window.rootViewController = NC;
```